# 'Free work' questions?

Tags: discussion

There was just a question on the site which is pretty much a 'do my homework' kind of thing (except in our case it would be a 'do my custom programming for free'):

[Best way to automate the page/post publication process?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11770/best-way-to-automate-the-page-post-publication-process)

How do we handle these? I down-voted it and added a comment.

Do we need to update the FAQ to make it more explicitly clear that this type of question is not welcome? It's *not* welcome, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see this specific question as such. It is quite generic and merely asks for best approach for importing data of specific kind.

If it was worded like *Here is link to the file, I want the code to import it (preferably fast)* - maybe then...

There is a difference between asking interesting and possibly challenging question, related to paid work, (which I do myself) and asking someone to do your work without intent to put a single bit of effort into it.

In either case I have no issue with actual question being asked. I think community is quite capable of sorting it out with up/downvotes and picking genuinely interesting question worth answering.

Comment: Okay, seems I might have been overly critical of that qeustion, then. Maybe I hadn't had enough coffee yet or something. I'll try to be more open-minded.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this topic has been discussed before on Meta, but I searched for 10 minutes and couldn't find where that discussion occurred.

That being said, I don't have a problem in general with questions which relate to work the question-asker is being paid to do. However, if the question-asker is exhibiting laziness (obviously not putting effort into the question, and seeking a complete solution rather than just help learning how to do some specific task), then I'll probably downvote (and explain why).

Answer (score 4):

All/most of my questions have been work related in one way or another, in that the reason I'm searching for the answer is because of a work related scenario that I can't figure out on my own. Honestly, what other kinds of questions are there? Most all questions from professional WP people are going to relate to their work somehow.

In the cited example, the answers pointed in general directions, and the user is going to have to do a lot of work to get that to go together in the way they want.

However, anything obviously homework or something that requires a full time job to answer is surely out of the question?

Answer (score 4):

Hi **@Dougal Campbell:**

I have to concur with the others. Pretty much if it's a WordPress question it's okay. If the asker will participate in clarifying his or her question and select the best answer and vote up afterwards then his or her questions are welcome.

There are been a few people who have posted 25+ questions here who are obviously getting paid for their work and I've noticed they don't seem to be learning from all the answers given to them, but then I think *"Maybe it's just not their aptitude?"*, and they do *"reward"* the answers with selections and votes so it's all good.

*(I do sometimes get annoyed when I click through to their websites and see that they claim they are a "Leading WordPress Expert" and I think "Are you kidding me?", but I keep those thoughts regarding specific people to myself and still answer their questions cause that's what we are here for. :)*

Comment: +1 I agree with you. Excellently stated. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Came over to meta to ask just this question, with the suspicion that a particular question crosses the line - this one: [Integrating custom API for post content into Admin interface & Public Website](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/29544)

It's already been edited down from a larger spec - but the OP is still looking for an entire custom dev project out of a single question.

Even if it wasn't just a bit much to ask for a 'completely coded solution' -- I don't think it's good for the site when questions aren't tightly focused on a single issue - hence my comment that the OP break it down into several discrete questions.

Was I out of line?

Comment: That definitely looks like case "work for me for free". Also please use flags to get moderator attention, it is easy to miss things on meta.

Comment: Yeah - been a bit leery of flags since I noticed my flag weight.  Going 1 for 3 means I need a better understanding of what to flag - hence asking here.  The OP had a duplicate of the question which I just flagged.  Just to be clear, the OP didn't re-post after you closed the first one.  I'm not sure what the intent was.